# Typescript private properties encapsulation conventions

Tags: angular, typescript, encapsulation

Question:  What is the best practice for naming private properties in Typescript and should one as a rule create a “get and set” for that property?

Reading the following link gave me pause to what I thought would be a good practice for coding Typescript:  https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Coding-guidelines

I understand his qualifier to his coding guideline that this is not a prescriptive guideline, however, his convention on naming private properties brings up questions in my mind on proper encapsulation and use of private properties in Typescript.  The convention I have been following is to name the private properties with the prefix of underscore and then create a get and set that I use to assign or get the value from that property.  Back in Anders’ Delphi days that convention is what made it a property and not just another variable. That property gave it characteristic that allowed for tooling.

Example:

```
…
private _progress: IImportInfo[];
…
get progress(): IImportInfo[] {
  return this._progress;
}

set progress(value: IImportInfo[]) {
  this._progress = value;
}
…
```

So from an html file you would get the values from the property as such:

```
<li *ngFor="let item of progress">
```

However, you could access it as such:

```
<li *ngFor="let item of _progress">
```

So access to the private variable from the outside is allowed.  The encapsulation nature you would normally get with a private variable does not exist, however, there is some value in adhering to encapsulation rules (IMO).  However, the purpose in asking this question is not about “my opinion”.  I would like to know what more experience angular/typescript developers feel is a best practice in dealing with Typescript private properties.  Better yet a link to a site (with credibility) of a “best practice” for dealing with private properties.

Thanks in advance for any help on this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer I was looking for:

https://angular.io/guide/styleguide

Properties and methods
Style 03-04
Do use lower camel case to name properties and methods.

Avoid prefixing private properties and methods with an underscore.

Why? Follows conventional thinking for properties and methods.

Why? JavaScript lacks a true private property or method.

Why? TypeScript tooling makes it easy to identify private vs. public properties and methods.

Comment: The Angular style guide appears to have been updated to remove the recommendation to avoid underscore prefixes for private properties: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/26393